# SAS SGPLOT with a calculated field for Y axis

Tags: sas

Hello I would like to plot a Series SGPLOT where the Y axis is the percentage of a ratio of two values.
For example I have:

```
 |Month|Chickens_sold|Total_sold|
 |-----|-------------|----------|
 |01   |5            |10        |
 |02   |6            |13        |
 |03   |4            |11        |
 |04   |9            |9         |
```

I want a graph that has Month for the x axis and y is a calculated field of (Chicken_sold/Total_sold*100)

my code is something like this:

```
PROC SGPLOT DATA=Farm;
SERIES x=Month y=(Chicken_sold/Total_sold*100);
RUN;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your calculation within your dataset first.

```
data want;
    set farm;
    percent = Chicken_sold/Total_sold*100;
run;

proc sgplot data=want;
    series x = month y = percent;
run;
```

Note that in CAS Actions on Viya, the concept of a calculated variable like this is valid and can be done. This is done with the `computedVars` and `computedVarsProgram` statements.

There are many other SAS PROCs that also let you run programs or functions within them, but SGPLOT is not one of them. Generally SGPLOT is designed around prepared data.

Comment: Thanks!  I was trying to do it all in one PROC.  Didn't even think about splitting it up...